# FFMPEG - Extracting a frame from .mov doesnt work (multiply errors)

Tags: linux, ffmpeg

When I tra to extract q frame at second 1 from a video file it says this:
(running via ssh on synology diskstation with ffmpeg installed) 
Error with output (COMMAND ON TOP) (https://i.stack.imgur.com/hhUyA.jpg)

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/1375270

Comment: sry for the late reply, I noticed the version of ffmpeg installed was too old. ran perfectly find on windows machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My ffmpeg was outdated and didnt support currrent switches and options.